# How to login in feature specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I have a helper method that is using @request.env and Devise to login the user:

```
def login_user(user)
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  sign_in user
end
```

I'm trying to write a feature spec where I need to login, but login_user is failing:

```
1) Search finds a manufacturer
 Failure/Error: @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/support/controller_macros.rb:3:in `login_user'
 # ./spec/features/search_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I fix? I have no experience with feature specs, with cucumber I'd use a feature to login, I'm definitely not sure that's the best practice with rspecs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Capybara as well to connect your test user. In my rails_helper I have this method:

```
def create_user_and_log_in
  create :user, email: 'user@test.com', password: 'password'
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in :user_email, with: 'user@test.com'
  fill_in :user_password, with: 'password'
  click_on 'Connexion'
end
```

You can then call this method in your specs.

Comment: One thing to note on larger applications with more assets, DB relationships, &c is that a login strategy that uses Capybara's DOM traversal is a lot slower than stubbing a helper method like `current_user` (see Duch's answer below).

Answer (score 4):

In Capybara feature specs in my app, we use the Warden test helpers:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  Warden.test_mode!
end

# in the feature spec
login_as(user, scope: :user)
```

Also, for controller specs:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was working with different library then Devise but it should works. It's very simple mock:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user) { user }
```

You can make it even simpler by making a special helper:

```
# spec/support/feature_spec_helper.rb`

module FeatureSpecHelper
  def login(user)
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user) { user }
  end
end
```

Then in spec config (spec_helper or rails_helper) drop anywhere

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
# (...)
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FeatureSpecHelper, :type => :feature
# (...)
```

next you can use in feature spec `login user`